# how to move logo to top in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below website `http://olisvell.com/responsivedesign/index.html` logo i want to move to top.
My log was displaying little bit down i want to move to top.above one is my website link.thing working fine except the logo

every
Can anyone please help me

**html**

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-right">
                <p class="right">Welcome Guest<span>Free Register</span><span>Login</span></p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                  <br>
                <select class="right">
                    <option>Select Language</option>
                    <option>English</option>
                </select>
<br>
                <div class="clear"></div>
<br>
                <p class="right">Powered by Google Translate</p>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- //header -->
<!-- navigation -->
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>


<div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt=""/></a>

    </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Treatments</a></li>


                <li><a href="index.html">Partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Visa Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
   .logo {
      float: left;
    }
    .logo a {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .header {
      margin: 10px 0;
    }
    .container{ direction: ltr }
    .header-right .right{ float: right }
    .header-right .right span{ margin-left: 20px }
    .clear{ clear: both }
    .nav-wil{

float: right;
margin-top:10px;

}
```

Comment: Why you dont move that code for displaying your logo to your <div class="header"> ?

Comment: after moving logo into header means lang and menu was displaying down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.header {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.container{ direction: ltr }
.header-right, .header-right .right{ float: right }
.header-right .right span{ margin-left: 20px }
.clear{ clear: both }
.navbar-nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 11px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="http://olisvell.com/responsivedesign/images/logo.gif" alt=""/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <p class="right">Welcome Guest<span>Free Register</span><span>Login</span></p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <select class="right">
                <option>Select Language</option>
                <option>English</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="right">Powered by Google Translate</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Treatments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Visa Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my answer to put navigation at the right side too. You may see its not on the right here on stackoverflow code snippet, because of tight width of the div section. please give it a try on your website

Answer (score 1):

This might help you on the way:

```
<style>
    .header-left
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .header-right
    {
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

and the adjusted html (don't forget to remove your logo further one)

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-left">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.gif" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <p class="right">Welcome Guest<span>Free Register</span><span>Login</span></p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <br>
            <select class="right">
                <option>Select Language</option>
                <option>English</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <br>
            <p class="right">Powered by Google Translate</p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
example: `<img style="position:absolute; top:0px;" src=logo.png>`
Very simple, this will move your logo/image to very top.